# How do I restrict access to files with a Tomcat server?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm currently using Java when a user needs to interact with the database. It checks for the appropriate log information from the authenticator.

But now I'm serving a PDF file that is on the server. Not all users should have access to this file -or this directory for that matter.

How can I restrict access to it?

In my naïve understanding, I thought about restricting access using Java/JSP, but when the user actually gets the URL with the full path on the server to the file, anyone can access it.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to access a pdf file from your local computer stored at some location, and this file have restricted the previleges?

Comment: Too broad question. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and describe you problem and what have you tried so far with more detail.

Comment: @ericbn it's not broad. You can easily do this using a servlet filter.

Comment: I tried adding some more information, I think servlet filter is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Servlet Filter for it. The servlet filter should be mapped to the URL to access to this PDF files. For example:

```
@WebFilter("/path/to/your/pdf/*")
public class FileFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
            if (validateUserForPdfDownload(user)) {
                //user can download the file
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } else {
                //user must not download the file
                //redirect user to some URL
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.html");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean validateUserForPdfDownload(User user) {
        //define the logic to validate if user is able to download the file
    }
}
```

Note that this is a basic approach. A more complex solution involves using a security framework to validate user authentication and authorization per action. You can use a framework like [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) or [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) to fulfill this requirement.

More info:

- [StackOverflow Servlets Filter Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to just authentication, you should have a permission system. You should define a set of permissions, and each user should have a subset of these permissions associated with it. Each object you are protecting should also have an associated permission. You should then check whether the authenticated user has the permission the served object requires.

This is the general idea. The actual implementation, the kind of permissions, whether there is a hierarchy between permissions (e.g. if you have "management" permission, you also have "pdf access" permissions) and the like are all dictated by the needs of the organization for which this is written.

Comment: Can you point me to some more literature or terminology that I can learn more about permission systems?